Некорректный поиск в Windows 10
Сложилась такая проблема. Произвожу поиск на Windows 10 в проводнике с помощью масок файла, но находятся лишние результаты.
Задача следующая:
Найти файлы, в названии которых содержится буква "ы".
Проблема решается, если вводить

∗ы∗.∗

но непонятно, почему лишние файлы возникают для маски

∗ы∗

Поиск по содержимому файлов отключен. Не понимаю, как он вообще находит это ы, потому что делает он это только для rtf и txt-файлов.

Заранее спасибо!
Ссылка на скачивание папки с файлами

Очень странно  Параметры -> Поиск -> Параметры поиска Windows -> Параметры индексирования -> Параметры индексирования -> Дополнительно точно не стоит галочки Искать по содержимому файлов

У меня на машине поиск работает верно(но может это из-за win11), можете после отключения поиска по содержимому, удалить индексы
